# Does String.Intern method just add a reference to a string to the intern pool or it creates a copy of the string?

Tags: c#, .net, string-interning

Suppose I have a string 'str'. I want to intern it using String.Intern method. I just wonder, how exactly String.Intern works in case when value of 'str' hasn't been interned yet.
The description of the method from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-5.0) is following:

> The Intern method uses the intern pool to search for a string equal to
> the value of str. If such a string exists, its reference in the intern
> pool is returned. If the string does not exist, **a reference to str is
> added to the intern pool, then that reference is returned.**

But this excerpt from a book "CLR via C#" tells differently:

> Intern, takes a String, obtains a hash code for it, and checks the
> internal hash table for a match. If an identical string already
> exists, a reference to the already existing String object is returned.
> If an identical string doesn’t exist, **a copy of the string is made,
> the copy is added to the internal hash table, and a reference to this
> copy is returned.**

I guess a description from the documentation is correct. So, only a reference to str is added to the intern pool without copying string object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy enough to test directly:

```cs
// Make string from char[] to ensure it's not already interned
string s1 = new string(new[] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });
string i1 = string.Intern(s1);
bool result1 = object.ReferenceEquals(s1, i1);

string s2 = new string(new[] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });
string i2 = string.Intern(s2);
bool result2 = object.ReferenceEquals(s2, i2);
```

Note that `result1` is set to `true`, showing that the original `string` object is not copied. On the other hand, `result2` is set to `false`, showing that the second constructed `string` object `"Hello"` was found in the intern pool, and so the `string.Intern()` method returns that interned instance instead of the newly constructed instance passed in.

The `string.Intern()` method does not copy strings. It just checks whether the reference passed is equal to a string already in the pool, and adds it to the pool if it's not.